# Zend Framework strange class loading

Tags: zend-framework

I can't understand some strange thing.
I have folder structure:

```
application/
  controllers/
  forms/
  models/
  views/
```

I added Service folder to 'models' folder and create file in it:

```
models/
  Service/
    User.php
```

models/Service/User.php:

```
<?php

  class Model_Service_User {}
```

In IndexController (for testing):

```
....
$test = new Model_Service_User; // It's works
....
```

But I don't understand why if I add 'Mapper' folder as 'Service' one, it is not working..

```
models/
  Mapper/
    User.php
```

models/Mapper/User.php:

```
<?php

  class Model_Mapper_User {}
```

And in IndexController:

```
....
$test = new Model_Mapper_User; // Fatal error: Class 'Model_Mapper_User' not found
....
```

I try to create another folders like 'Map', 'Maps' and so, they are working ok. But what is wrong with Mapper??

Comment: Where is the models/Service/User.php getting included?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because there is a resource autoloader definition for `Model_Mapper` already defined in [`Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader`](http://framework.zend.com/svn/framework/standard/trunk/library/Zend/Application/Module/Autoloader.php).

The autoloader looks for these class files in `/models/mappers`.

If you want to remove this mapping, in your `Bootstrap` class, try this...

```
protected function _initResourceAutoloader()
{
    $autoloader = $this->getResourceLoader();
    $autoloader->removeResourceType('mappers');
}
```

... or you could just put your mappers in `models/mappers`.